# Read all images in one column, include the base64 string result to image html tag. XPage

Tags: html, database, image, base64, xpages

as you can see the code below it can translate the image data from lotus database to a base64 string. The problem is I manually put the file name of the image (line 4). I have a lots of images on my database and only my "btnbg.jpg"  can read it, the others are not. How can my code can read all the image file names inside the database column. Also how can I include the result base64 string to my html image tag. Thank you so much and God bless

```
var testView:NotesView = database.getView("uploadforms");
    var col:NotesDocumentCollection = testView.getAllDocumentsByKey("1");
    var testDoc:NotesDocument = col.getFirstDocument();
    var attachment:NotesEmbeddedObject = testDoc.getAttachment("btnbg.jpg");
    var input:java.io.InputStream = attachment.getInputStream();

    var base64Enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
    var output = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    base64Enc.encode( input, output );

    return output.toString();
```

Comment: did you try to add column with @AttachmentNames formula and get attachment name by getColumnValues() method?

Answer (score 1):

> "How can my code can read all the image file names inside the database column"

You need to print attachment names in to the column. For example with the help of "@AttachmentNames" function.
You need o use "ViewNavigator" class to traverse column exactly

If you are prefer to work with document, then use some of the methods go get all attachment from document, like "EmbeddedObjects" method on the document and RT items.

> "how can I include the result base64 string to my html image tag"

You could do it with the help of css: background:url(data:image/jpeg;base64,...

It's a bad idea to use a lot of pictures in the css base64.

Comment: Actually the img tag takes data as url argument too: img
src="data:image/gif;base64,...